# adding pandas df to dask df

Tags: pandas, concatenation, dask, assign

One of the recent problems with dask I encountered was encodings that take a lot of time and I wanted to speed them up.

Problem: given a dask df (ddf), encode it, and return ddf.

Here is some code to start with:

```
# !pip install feature_engine

import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from feature_engine.encoding import CountFrequencyEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, (100,3)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

# make it object cols
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(str)

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

x_freq = ddf.copy()

for col_idx, col_name in enumerate(x_freq.columns):
    freq_enc = CountFrequencyEncoder(encoding_method='frequency')
    col_to_encode = x_freq[col_name].to_frame().compute()
    encoded_col = freq_enc.fit_transform(col_to_encode).rename(columns={col_name: col_name + '_freq'})
    
    x_freq = dd.concat([x_freq, encoded_col], axis=1)

x_freq.head()
```

It will run fine as I would expect, adding pandas df to dask df - no problem.
But when I try another ddf, there is an error:

```
x_freq = x.copy()
# npartitions = x_freq.npartitions
# x_freq = x_freq.repartition(npartitions=npartitions).reset_index(drop=True)

for col_idx, col_name in enumerate(x_freq.columns):
    freq_enc = CountFrequencyEncoder(encoding_method='frequency')
    col_to_encode = x_freq[col_name].to_frame().compute()
    encoded_col = freq_enc.fit_transform(col_to_encode).rename(columns={col_name: col_name + '_freq'})

    x_freq = dd.concat([x_freq, encoded_col], axis=1) 
    break

x_freq.head()
```

Error is happening during concat:

```
ValueError: Unable to concatenate DataFrame with unknown division specifying axis=1
```

This is how I load "error" ddf:

```
ddf = dd.read_parquet(os.path.join(dir_list[0], '*.parquet'), engine='pyarrow').repartition(partition_size='100MB')
```

I read I should try repartition and/or reset index and/or use assign. Neither worked.

```
x_freq = x.copy()
```

in the second example is similar to:

```
x_freq = ddf.copy()
```

in the first example in a sense that x is just some ddf I'm trying to encode but it would be a lot of code to define it here.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Should `x_freq = x.copy()` actuall be `x_freq = x_freq.copy()`? `x` is not defined anywhere

Comment: You are referring to the second example with which I have an error. It would be too much code to define x here. x = features of ddf, where ddf = x features and y target. I'm making a copy of it as there are be some other transformations and I don't want to accidentally change x.
Because x is hard to define I wrote a made-up example with some random data, but surprisingly it works as intended or at least as I would expect it to work. So I wonder maybe someone know how to fix the ValueError I'm having where it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: I'd be easier to answer this question if it was a [MCVE](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think might be going on.

Your parquet file probably doesn't have divisions information within it. You thus cannot just `dd.concat`, since it's not clear how the partitions align.

You can check this by

```py
x_freq.known_divisions # is likely False
x_freq.divisions # is likely (None, None, None, None)
```

Since unknown divisions are the problem, you can re-create the issue by using the synthetic data in the first example

```py
x_freq = ddf.clear_divisions().copy()
```

You might solve this problem by re-setting the index:

```py
x_freq.reset_index().set_index(index_column_name)
```

where `index_column_name` is the name of the index column.

Consider also saving the data with the correct index afterwards so that it doesn't have to be calculated each time.

#### Note 1: Parallelization

By the way, since you're computing each column before working with it, you're not really utilizing dask's parallelization abilities. Here is a workflow that might utilize parallelization a bit better:

```py
def count_frequency_encoder(s):
    return s.replace(s.value_counts(normalize=True).compute().to_dict())

frequency_columns = {
             f'{col_name}_freq': count_frequency_encoder(x_freq[col_name]) 
             for col_name in x_freq.columns}

x_freq = x_freq.assign(**frequency_columns)
```

#### Note 2: `to_frame`

A tiny tip:

```py
x_freq[col_name].to_frame()
```

is equivalent to

```py
x_freq[[col_name]]
```